# How can I deactivate parent's title on child hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
$.fn.right = function() {
   return $(document).width() - (this.offset().left + this.outerWidth());
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    this.iid = setTimeout(function() {
      var tag_name = self.text(),
          top      = self.position().top + self.outerHeight(true),
          right = self.right();
      $('body').append("<div class='tag_info'>Some explanations about "+tag_name+"</div>");
      
      $(".tag_info").css({top: top + "px", right: right + "px"}).fadeIn(200);  
      
    }, 525);
  }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
    if(this.iid){
      clearTimeout(this.iid)
      $('.tag_info').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
    body{
      padding: 20px;
      direction: rtl;
    }
   
    div {
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }
 
    a {
        color: #3e6d8e !important;
        background-color: #E1ECF4;
        padding: 2px 5px;
    }
    .tag_info{
      position: absolute;
      width: 130px;
      height: 100px;
      display:none;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div title='a title'>
         <a>long-length-tag</a>
         <a>tag</a>
    </div>
```

As you see, there is a dark popup on tags hover. Also div's title will be appear when that popup shows. How can I disable the title? *(on tags hover)*

Comment: you should take off the title attribute.

Comment: @smerny Well I need it for other areas of the `div`.

Comment: you could remove/re-add it with js if you want (at the same time you are showing the popup)

Answer (score 0):

The title hover is a per browser thing.

A better option would be to remove the `title` property when you add the hover over option.

```
/// somewhere in your hover in function
element.oldTitle = element.title;
element.title = '';
```

---

```
/// somewhere in your hover out function 
element.title = element.oldTitle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code on the mouseenter event:

```
$(this).parent().data('title', $(this).parent().attr('title'));
$(this).parent().attr('title', '');
```

.. and this on the mouseleave:

```
$(this).parent().attr('title', $(this).parent().data('title') );
```

```js
$.fn.right = function() {
   return $(document).width() - (this.offset().left + this.outerWidth());
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var self = $(this);

    $(this).parent().data('title', $(this).parent().attr('title'));
    $(this).parent().attr('title', '');

    this.iid = setTimeout(function() {
      var tag_name = self.text(),
          top      = self.position().top + self.outerHeight(true),
          right = self.right();
      $('body').append("<div class='tag_info'>Some explanations about "+tag_name+"</div>");
      
      $(".tag_info").css({top: top + "px", right: right + "px"}).fadeIn(200);  
      
    }, 525);
  }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
     
    $(this).parent().attr('title', $(this).parent().data('title') );

    if(this.iid){
      clearTimeout(this.iid)
      $('.tag_info').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
    body{
      padding: 20px;
      direction: rtl;
    }
   
    div {
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }
 
    a {
        color: #3e6d8e !important;
        background-color: #E1ECF4;
        padding: 2px 5px;
    }
    .tag_info{
      position: absolute;
      width: 130px;
      height: 100px;
      display:none;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div title='a title'>
         <a>long-length-tag</a>
         <a>tag</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: The title should only be disabled on tag hover, as asked in the question

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. When your mouse enters the tag, the current title will be set in the `oldTitle` attribute. When mouse leaves the tag, the current title will take its old value from the `oldTitle` attribute.

```js
$.fn.right = function() {
   return $(document).width() - (this.offset().left + this.outerWidth());
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    
    //get title and set it in a new attribute of the div
    var container = $(this).closest('div');
    container.attr('oldTitle', container.attr('title'));
    container.attr('title', '');
    
    this.iid = setTimeout(function() {
      var tag_name = self.text(),
          top      = self.position().top + self.outerHeight(true),
          right = self.right();
      $('body').append("<div class='tag_info'>Some explanations about "+tag_name+"</div>");
      
      $(".tag_info").css({top: top + "px", right: right + "px"}).fadeIn(200);  
      
    }, 525);
  }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
    if(this.iid){
      clearTimeout(this.iid)
      $('.tag_info').remove();
      
      //reactivate the title
      var container = $(this).closest('div');
      container.attr('title', container.attr('oldTitle'));
    }
  });
});

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```css
    body{
      padding: 20px;
      direction: rtl;
    }
   
    div {
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }
 
    a {
        color: #3e6d8e !important;
        background-color: #E1ECF4;
        padding: 2px 5px;
    }
    .tag_info{
      position: absolute;
      width: 130px;
      height: 100px;
      display:none;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div title='a title'>
         <a>long-length-tag</a>
         <a>tag</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Add an empty title attribute on the child element.

You can add an empty title attribute to your `a` elements to resolve this issue. The empty tag on the children will prevent the parent title from showing...

See the changed code example below.

```js
$.fn.right = function() {
   return $(document).width() - (this.offset().left + this.outerWidth());
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    this.iid = setTimeout(function() {
      var tag_name = self.text(),
          top      = self.position().top + self.outerHeight(true),
          right = self.right();
      $('body').append("<div class='tag_info'>Some explanations about "+tag_name+"</div>");
      
      $(".tag_info").css({top: top + "px", right: right + "px"}).fadeIn(200);  
      
    }, 525);
  }).bind('mouseleave', function(){
    if(this.iid){
      clearTimeout(this.iid)
      $('.tag_info').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
    body{
      padding: 20px;
      direction: rtl;
    }
   
    div {
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }
 
    a {
        color: #3e6d8e !important;
        background-color: #E1ECF4;
        padding: 2px 5px;
    }
    .tag_info{
      position: absolute;
      width: 130px;
      height: 100px;
      display:none;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div title='a title'>
         <a title="">long-length-tag</a>
         <a title="">tag</a>
    </div>
```